# Can I use CloudFront with an EFS where content is split across users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-efs

I use an EFS on an EC2 instance with per-user writable subdirectories. Basically, user `john` has his images served from `/home/john/images` and user `sally` has her images served from `/home/sally/images` with virtual hosts set up for each user.

I was hoping to use CloudFront to reduce my Data Transfer costs, but I'm not sure how I'd configure CloudFront to serve the image content for all users using a single origin domain.

Is there a way to set up some kind of pattern matching in CloudFront to achieve something like this?

`cdn.mywebsite.com/john` => `/home/john/images`
`cdn.mywebsite.com/sally` => `/home/sally/images`

Comment: This seems entirely dependent on the web server software you have running on the EC2 instance, and the fact that those user folders happen to be saved in EFS instead of EBS is irrelevant to what you are trying to do. It's not like CloudFront serves files directly from EFS, it's just going to proxy requests to your Apache web server, and Apache needs to be configured appropriately to serve all those user's folders.

Comment: I guess what I’m asking is how can I map those proxy requests to the correct content on my server? Can I include information about the user in the CDN url so I know which directory to point to?